# Understanding this and constructors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a Java background and looking to understanding constructors and the this keyword in JavaScript.

I came across this code which seems to be pretty straightforward

```
var Mediator = ( function( window, undefined ) {

function Mediator() {
this._topics = {};
}

Mediator.prototype.subscribe = function mediatorSubscribe( topic, callback ) {
if( ! this._topics.hasOwnProperty( topic ) ) {
this._topics[ topic ] = [];
}

this._topics[ topic ].push( callback );
return true;
};

Mediator.prototype.unsubscribe = function mediatorUnsubscrive( topic, callback ) {
if( ! this._topics.hasOwnProperty( topic ) ) {
return false;
}

for( var i = 0, len = this._topics[ topic ].length; i < len; i++ ) {
if( this._topics[ topic ][ i ] === callback ) {
this._topics[ topic ].splice( i, 1 );
return true;
}
}

return false;
};

Mediator.prototype.publish = function mediatorPublish() {
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );
var topic = args.shift();

if( ! this._topics.hasOwnProperty( topic ) ) {
return false;
}

for( var i = 0, len = this._topics[ topic ].length; i < len; i++ ) {
this._topics[ topic ][ i ].apply( undefined, args );
}
return true;
};

return Mediator;

} )( window );

// example subscriber function
var Subscriber = function ExampleSubscriber( myVariable ) {
console.log( myVariable );
};

// example usages
var myMediator = new Mediator();
myMediator.subscribe( 'some event', Subscriber );
myMediator.publish( 'some event', 'foo bar' ); // console logs "foo bar"
```

I see that the constructor sets a property in the object called _topics

I tried to replicate the same logic in a simple version abstracting away only the constructor to see the behavior.

```
var x=(function(){function x(){console.log('asdf')} return x;})();
var y=new x()
```

And I get an error that undefined is not a function.

I am returning x in the IIFE so what's going wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "And I get an error that undefined is not a function." --- given 2 lines work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/c993Y/

Comment: zerkms is right. right click this very site and run it in console. asdf is logged

Comment: thanks i don't know what i was doing wrong. it works fine

Comment: The [Javascript Garden section](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this) on `this` is a very helpful reference.

Answer (score 4):

The value of this in JavaScript refers to the execution context of the function. In JavaScript there are three execution context; namely global, function and evaluation. Following example will help to comprehend the concept better.

**Global context:**

In the global context this refers to the window object.

```
console.log(this) // Window
```

**Function context:**

In JavaScript a function can be invoked in five different patterns: method invocation, function invocation, constructor invocation, apply invocation and call invocation. The value of this within the function context depends on how the function has been invoked.

***Method invocation:***

In method invocation pattern this refers to the object (on which the method has been invoked) itself. The value of this gets binded to the object at the time of invocation.

```
var foo = {
    bar : function() {
       console.log(this);
       return this;
    }
}

console.log(foo.bar()) // Object; that refers to foo

var foo = {
    bar : function() {
       return this;
    }
}

console.log(foo === foo.bar()); // true; 'this' returned by bar is nothing but foo
```

***Function invocation:***

In function invocation pattern this refers to the window object. In the broader perspective even function invocation pattern is nothing but method invocation pattern. The context of the function is window. Lets consider we have a named function baz as below:

```
var baz = function() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

In the function invocation pattern baz can be invoked as:

```
baz(); // Window
```

However baz can also be invoked as:

```
window.baz(); // Window; as stated in method invocation pattern
```

All the globals (variables, objects, functions) are associated with window and as per the specification, when referring a global the window reference can be omitted. Thus window refers to the global context in function invocation pattern.

***Constructor Invocation:***

In the constructor invocation pattern, when a function is invoked with new operator, this refers to the new object that gets created and returned by the function (provide there is no explicit return statement).

```
var Foo = function () {// By convention the constructor name starts with upper case letter
    console.log(this); // Foo
}
```

The above code is can be interpreted as

```
var Foo = function () {// By convention the constructor name starts with upper case letter
    // create a new object
    // using the object literal
    // var this = {};
    console.log(this); // Foo, only when invoked as new Foo(); otherwise this will refer to Window
    // return this;
}
```

A lot more needs to be said about constructor, which will be taken up in a separate post.

**Apply Invocation & Call Invocation:**

Apply and Call invocation differs the way argument is treated. But with respect to this both the pattern behaves in the same way. In the beauty of these two pattern is that this can be set to any desired context.

```
var bar = {}

var qux = function () {
    console.log(this);
}

qux.apply(bar) // Object; that refers to bar

qux.call(bar) // Object; that refers to foo
```

**Evaluation context:**

In evaluation context the value of this refers to the parents context.

```
eval('console.log(this)') // Window

var foo = {
    bar : function() {
       eval('console.log(this)')
    }
}

foo.bar(); // Object; that refers to foo
```

A word of caution: One should refrain from using eval, most of the JavaScript ninjas and gurus consider “eval is evil”. However, I feel that eval is too powerful to be utilized. Improper utilization can produce unexpected results, which can be really frightening.

Comment: FWIW, there is only one type of execution context. The `this` value is a characteristic of an execution context (http://es5.github.io/#x10.3). It's true though that an execution context is either created by entering global scope, a function, or `eval` (http://es5.github.io/#x10.4). Regarding `eval`, the execution context additionally depends on whether `eval` is called directly or indirectly (i.e. it is not always the same as the "parent context").